# Applying a formula to a column in excel python

Tags: python, excel

On Python 3.9.

So here's what I'm trying to do. I'm running reports almost every hour and they aren't formatted when exported to excel to the way I need them to be.

I'm essentially trying to figure out a way to start on the second row (since I have headers) and apply =RIGHT(Ax, 10) to each row in the column A such as =RIGHT(A2, 10), =RIGHT(A3, 10), =RIGHT(A4, 10), and so on until the last row in the workbook. Each workbook will have an arbitrary number of rows since it changes (increases) as the day goes on.

```
import csv
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active  

with open(r'location\file.csv') as f: 
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',') 
    for row in reader:
        ws.append(row) 

wb.save(r'location\file.xlsx') 

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'location\file.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet']
maxr = sheet.max_row
tuple(sheet[f'A2:{maxr}'])
sheet[f'A2:A{maxr}'] = f"=RIGHT(A2:A{maxr}, 10)"

wb.save(r'location\file.xlsx')
```

Comment: It looks like you're creating a new Workbook `wb`, saving it, and then re-opening it?

Comment: Well the report first downloads it as a csv but I need it in xlsx so I basically created a clone and made it xlsx. I'd want to use the =RIGHT and other functions on the xlsx file.

Answer (score 1):

Try to keep it simple. Give the following a try.

Change this section of your code

```
maxr = sheet.max_row
tuple(sheet[f'A2:{maxr}'])
sheet[f'A2:A{maxr}'] = f"=RIGHT(A2:A{maxr}, 10)"
```

to a loop

```
maxr = len(sheet['A'])
for curr_row in range(2, maxr  + 1):
    curr_value = sheet.cell(row=curr_row, column=4).value 
    new_value = curr_value[-10:]
    sheet.cell(row=curr_row, column=4) = new_value
```

Comment: I'm getting an error of "cannot assign to function call"

Comment: Can you be more specific on the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```py
tuple(sheet[f'A2:{maxr}'])
sheet[f'A2:A{maxr}'] = f"=RIGHT(A2:A{maxr}, 10)"
```

with

```py
for i in range(1,maxr+1):
    sheet[f'A{i}'].value = sheet[f'A{i}'].value[-10:]
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything for column A. I'm also trying to do this from say column O while =RIGHT(Px, 10) x being the row number